# What is the meaning of thirdPartyFrameDomainSuffix in https://cdn.ampproject.org/caches.json

Tags: amp-html

Currently our project only support for Google's AMP Cache service, but we would like to support all the "authentic" AMP Cache Server. Checking the list of service from https://cdn.ampproject.org/caches.json, we know that cloudflare and bing is ready for use. Most of the value in the caches.json file is already self explanatory like:

cacheDomain: where the amp-html will be server from cache server.

updateCacheApiDomainSuffix: where we should call when our amp-html have updated content.

the only property we confused is `thirdPartyFrameDomainSuffix`.

Can someone explain what it is?

Answer (score -1):

I don't also see any documentation regarding `thirdPartyFrameDomainSuffix`. You may visit this [page](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#reporting-issues-with-amp) on how to get help.

> The AMP Project is meant to evolve with feedback. The project and its users appreciate your thoughts on ways to improve the design or features.
>
> To make a suggestion or feature request [file a GitHub issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new) describing your idea.
>
> If you are suggesting a feature that you are intending to implement, please see the [Contributing a new feature](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#phase-concept-design) section below for next steps.